# sed command to find a particular word

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

```
//ask.census.gov/
//ask.census.gov/
//business.usa.gov/
//directorsblog.blogs.census.gov/
//public.govdelivery.com/accounts/USCENSUS/subscriber/new
//twitter.com/uscensusbureau
//www.calendarwiz.com/calendars/calendar.php?crd=cens1sample&amp;cid[]=31793    
//www.census.gov/2017censustests    
//www.census.gov/2017censustests/    
//www.census.gov/2020census    
//www.census.gov/2020census    
//www.census.gov/2020census/
//www.census.gov/about.html    
//www.census.gov/about.html
```

I want the lines which have www in them by using sed command

Comment: Why `uniq`? It has a different purpose.

Comment: You should show your code. What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Thanks axiac and jww, I got my answer correct. I clearified it with my colleague and the assignment says that you can use any command not particularly uniq.

Comment: You're trying to use a screwdriver for a nail. Your hammer is grep.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed:

```
sed -ne '/\/www\./p' file
```

Or grep:

```
grep '/www\.' file
```

Or awk

```
awk '/\/www\./' file
```